# How to separate a string into a sentence without a proper patern

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a data that looks like this

```
Huawei Y7P Art-L28 (4/64gb) (AAAAAAAAAAAAAA) EXP:02/19/2020
Huawei Y9 prime 2019 (BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB) EXP:07/17/2019
Oppo A31 4gb/128gb (CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
Vivo Y15 5000mah 4GB/64GB (1901) (DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD) EXP:06/14/2019
```

And the I want to get this data

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Basically what I want to happen is to extract the data from the set of word but my problem here is that its very unpredictable. It has no pattern at all so its hard to separate the string.

Comment: @Strawberry done editing thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need a substring in last parenthesis:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '(', -1), ')', 1)
FROM source_table
```

Comment: Hi sir good afternoon. Does this code will apply in case the string position is unpredictable?

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente At this point, all we can say is that it works for the sample provided but, you know, GIGO

Comment: @Akina or maybe as long as we assume it is encapsulated in ()

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente You MUST predict. You MUST build a criteria which allows to distingiush what substring is needed. It can be complex, it may include substring content check for inclusions/exclusions or any other criteria - but it MUST exist.

Comment: Already confirm. The criteria must have atleas open close parenthesis

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente Not enough. Your sample data shows that the value may contain more than one substring enclosed in parenthesis. You MUST build a criteria which allows to distingiush what substring from all possible ones is needed. For example, it can be like "the substring must NOT contain digits"...

Comment: Thanks for the help. As of now I will use it and hope my sample will be the basis GIGO